Filter Button with Supabase and Next JS
Hi All fairly new to next JS and web development on a whole.
I have a page where I return all the values from properties table and populate the page with cards for each property.
This is the page.
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createClient } from '@/utils/supabase/server';
import Sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar';
import PropertyList from '@/components/PropertyList';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import PageHeader from '@/components/pageHeader';
import getProperties from '@/utils/supabase/getProperties';

interface Property {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
    image_url: string;
    rent_per_month: number;
    vacant: boolean;
}

const supabase = createClient();
const pageTitle = "Properties";

const Properties = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');
    const [properties, setProperties] = useState<Property[]>([]);
    
    useEffect (() => {
        async function getUser() {
            const fetchedUsers = await supabase.auth.getUser();
            setUser(fetchedUsers);
        }
    });

    if(!user) {
        redirect('')
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchProperties() {
            const fetchedProperties = await getProperties(filter);
            setProperties(fetchedProperties);
        }
        fetchProperties();
    }, [filter]);

    const handleClick = (filterValue: string) => {
        setFilter(filterValue);
    };

    const handleViewAll = () => {
        handleClick('');
    };

    const handleOccupied = () => {
        handleClick('occupied');
    };

    const handleVacant = () => {
        handleClick('vacant');
    };



    return (
        <div className="flex flex-row">
            <Sidebar user={user.user_metadata.firstName} organization={user.user_metadata.organization} />
            <div className="flex flex-col flex-grow">
                <PageHeader pageTitle={pageTitle} />
                <div className="inline-flex overflow-hidden bg-white border divide-x rounded-lg dark:bg-gray-900 rtl:flex-row-reverse dark:border-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-700">
                    <button onClick={handleViewAll} className="px-5 py-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-200 bg-gray-100 sm:text-sm dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300">
                        View all
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={handleOccupied} className="px-5 py-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-200 sm:text-sm dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100">
                        Occupied
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={handleVacant} className="px-5 py-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-200 sm:text-sm dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100">
                        Vacant
                    </button>
                </div>
                <PropertyList properties={properties} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Properties;


the buttons call the handle functions which in turn call fetch properties im abit lost on how to do this I dont want to do server side rendering but the issue is the supabase create client import headers as it does some cookie stuff and this means it has to be a server component. Im abit lost currently on hwo to do this can anyone shed any light on how to do this?
New Section:
I have now filtered out the filter button to its own component:
'use client';

import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function FilterButtonProperties({setProperties, filter, setFilter}) {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchProperties() {
            const fetchedProperties = await getProperties(filter);
            setProperties(fetchedProperties);
        }
        fetchProperties();
    }, [filter]);

    const handleFilter = (filterValue: string) => {
        setFilter(filterValue);
    };


    return (
        <div className="inline-flex overflow-hidden bg-white border divide-x rounded-lg dark:bg-gray-900 rtl:flex-row-reverse dark:border-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-700">
            <button onClick={() => handleFilter('')} className="px-5 py-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-200 bg-gray-100 sm:text-sm dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300">
                View all
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => handleFilter('Occupied')} className="px-5 py-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-200 sm:text-sm dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100">
                Occupied
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => handleFilter('Vacant')} className="px-5 py-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-200 sm:text-sm dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100">
                Vacant
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

Then in the main page.tsx
import { createClient } from '@/utils/supabase/server';
import Sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar';
import PropertyList from '@/components/PropertyList';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import PageHeader from '@/components/pageHeader';
import getProperties from '@/utils/supabase/getProperties';
import FilterButtonProperties from '@/components/FilterButtonProperties';

interface Property {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
    image_url: string;
    rent_per_month: number;
    vacant: boolean;
}

const supabase = createClient();
const pageTitle = "Properties";

export default async function Properties() {
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');
    const [properties, setProperties] = useState<Property[]>();

    const {
        data: { user },
    } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

    if (!user) {
        redirect('/login')
    }


    return (
        <div className="flex flex-row">
            <Sidebar user={user.user_metadata.firstName} organization={user.user_metadata.organization} />
            <div className="flex flex-col flex-grow">
                <PageHeader pageTitle={pageTitle} />
                <FilterButtonProperties setProperties={setProperties} filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter}/>
                <PropertyList properties={properties} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
function useState(arg0: string): [any, any] {
    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
}



I still have some issues now with state claiming the function isnt implemented.

You have to split your page into multiple components, the one that handles the event listeners should be the client component, and the rest is server component. In addition, use queryParams to get the values in your server components. I strongly encourage you to follow up with tutorials and documentation to expand your knowledge with NextJS since these principles are crucial to understand.

the page is split into components only thing that isnt is the filter button but cant see that being the whole issue?

keep in mind that you can't use hooks in server components and you can't handle event listeners. how are you thinking of achieving that if you did not split? supabase needs to be server component, but then onClick you want to filter and fetch data then that must be a client component.

sorry Im new to this and didnt understand how the use effect could be filtered back to the parent to set the state. I am now moving the filter section out to its own component.
